# Solidity Programming

Tags: function, solidity

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

```
contract crr019_week4assignment {
    
     // Student Account Structure
    struct StudentAccount {
        
        string Username;
        address Metamask;
        uint Age;
        string EmailAddress;
        bool BlockchainTrackEnrolled;
        StudentType ClassLevel;
        
    }
    
    constructor() public {
        
        
    }
    

    StudentAccount [] public StudentInformation;
    
    

     enum StudentType {
            Freshman,
            Sophomore, 
            Junior,
            Senior, 
            Graduate
        }

    
     function AddStudent (string  _Username, address  _Metamask, uint _Age, string  _EmailAddress, bool _BlockchainTrackEnrolled, StudentType  _ClassLevel ) public {
     
     // Anything inside of this function can use any of the parameters
     
     StudentAccount memory NewStudent = StudentAccount({Username:_Username, Metamask:_Metamask, Age:_Age, Email:_EmailAddress, BlockchainTrackEnrolled:_BlockchainTrackEnrolled,  Student:_ClassLevel});
     
     

 }
    


}
```

Getting TypeError: Named argument does not match functions declaration.

Answer (score 3):

**what you should correct in your smartcontract**

1. you must add memory after your string arguments
2. replace  email and student with EmailAddress and ClassLevel

[correct code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xwqU.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo when you are creating your struct instance : Use EmailAddress instead of Email.
Each property name used in your json ({}) must match names declared in the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The following correction has to be done in arguments and function declaration:

- instead of email you must use EmailAddress
- instead of Student you must use ClassLevel
- for string arguments you should use memory
  The corrected segment is as follow:

  function AddStudent (string memory _Username, address  _Metamask, uint _Age, string memory _EmailAddress, bool _BlockchainTrackEnrolled, StudentType  _ClassLevel ) public {

  ```
     // Anything inside of this function can use any of the parameters

     StudentAccount memory NewStudent = StudentAccount({Username:_Username, Metamask:_Metamask, Age:_Age, EmailAddress:_EmailAddress, BlockchainTrackEnrolled:_BlockchainTrackEnrolled,  ClassLevel:_ClassLevel});
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Naming should be done properly.
Corrected code :

```swift
pragma solidity 0.6.12; 
contract crr019_week4assignment {
    // Student Account Structure
    struct StudentAccount {
        string Username;
        address Metamask;
        uint Age;
        string EmailAddress;
        bool BlockchainTrackEnrolled;
        StudentType ClassLevel;
    }

    constructor() public { }
    StudentAccount [] public StudentInformation;
    enum StudentType {
        Freshman,
        Sophomore, 
        Junior,
        Senior, 
        Graduate
    }
    function AddStudent (string  memory _Username, address  _Metamask, uint _Age, string  memory _EmailAddress, bool _BlockchainTrackEnrolled, StudentType  _ClassLevel ) public {
        // Anything inside of this function can use any of the parameters
        StudentAccount memory NewStudent = StudentAccount({Username:_Username, Metamask:_Metamask, Age:_Age, EmailAddress:_EmailAddress, BlockchainTrackEnrolled:_BlockchainTrackEnrolled,  ClassLevel:_ClassLevel});
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract crr019_week4assignment {
    
    // Student Account Structure
    struct StudentAccount {
        string Username;
        address Metamask;
        uint Age;
        string EmailAddress;
        bool BlockchainTrackEnrolled;
        StudentType ClassLevel;
    }

    constructor() {}
    StudentAccount [] public StudentInformation;
    enum StudentType {
        Freshman,
        Sophomore, 
        Junior,
        Senior, 
        Graduate
    }

    function addStudent (string memory _Username, address  _Metamask, uint _Age, string memory _EmailAddress, bool _BlockchainTrackEnrolled, StudentType  _Classlevel) public {
            StudentAccount memory NewStudent = StudentAccount(_Username, _Metamask, _Age, _EmailAddress, _BlockchainTrackEnrolled, _Classlevel);
            StudentInformation.push(NewStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Inside function AddStudent correct the naming convention from email to EmailAddress. Also you can add memory after each string variable(not mandatory).